# Pandas groupby and rank - same rank for duplicates

Tags: pandas, unique, pandas-groupby, rank

Here is my dataframe:

```
my_df = pd.DataFrame({'group':['a','a', 'a','b','b'], 'date':['2017-01-02', '2017-01-02','2017-03-01',  '2018-02-05', '2018-04-06']})
my_df['date']= pd.to_datetime(my_df['date'], format = '%Y-%m-%d')
```

I would like to add rank per group, where same values would be assigned same rank.

Here is what I would like as output:

```
    date        group rank
0   2017-01-02      a 1
1   2017-01-02      a 1
2   2017-03-01      a 2
3   2018-02-05      b 1
4   2018-04-06      b 2
```

I guess I can do it by grouping twice and ranking and join back to original dataframe, but I wonder if there is faster way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just using `rank` with method `dense`

```
my_df.groupby(['group'])['date'].rank(method ='dense')
Out[6]: 
0    1.0
1    1.0
2    2.0
3    1.0
4    2.0
Name: date, dtype: float64
```

Comment: I saw this option in the docs, but failed to understand it properly

Answer (score 2):

You could use `transform` with factorize:

```
my_df['group_rank'] = my_df.groupby(['group'])['date'].transform(lambda x: x.factorize()[0])

>>> my_df
        date group  group_rank
0 2017-01-02     a           0
1 2017-01-02     a           0
2 2017-03-01     a           1
3 2018-02-05     b           0
4 2018-04-06     b           1
```

If you add `+ 1` to the end of that, it will be ranks of 1 and 2 as in your desired output, but I thought this might not be important (since they are properly binned together in any case)

Comment: I wish I could accept both answers. Your approach is much more universal, does not require remembering options of `rank` function

Comment: Thanks, I think @Wen's rank method will end up being faster though.